# GetSystemTimeAsFileTime call using __int64 param

Tags: c++

My question is academic.  Can anyone tell me why several least sig bits are changed if I try a shortcut and use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` directly with a call using a `__int64` param ?

```
FILETIME fileTimeUTC;
__int64  timeUTC_64;
__int64  timeUTC_64Test;

GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&fileTimeUTC);    
memcpy(&timeUTC_64, &fileTimeUTC, sizeof(__int64 ));
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime((FILETIME*)&timeUTC_64Test);
ATLASSERT(sizeof(__int64) == sizeof(FILETIME)); // okay
ATLASSERT(timeUTC_64 == timeUTC_64Test); // FAILS !
```

Answer (score 5):

You're seeing a small difference in the low-order bits simply because the system time advances a small amount (probably on the order of several microseconds) in between the two calls.  It takes a non-infinitesimal amount of time just to get the current system time.

Also, as the documentation for the [`FILETIME` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notes, you should *not* be doing any casting here with `FILETIME` instances:

> Do not cast a pointer to a `FILETIME` structure to either a `ULARGE_INTEGER*` or `__int64*` value because it can cause alignment faults on 64-bit Windows.

Just use a `FILETIME` instance and convert it manually to a 64-bit value if you need to do math on it in order to avoid the possibility of alignment faults on 64-bit windows.

Comment: I know how to write the code so it works properly and I understand that the two calls would produce a time difference.   My question was academic in nature. What is it about casting this structure that triggers an alignment fault?  The answer has to do with internals, of course.